# How do I create a SINGLE symbolic link for Firejail, in Ubuntu/Fedora/CentOS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, symbolic-link, firejail

Firecfg will configure all symbolic links at once, but how do I create a single symbolic link to firejail a specific application that isn't securely preconfigured by for example, SELinux?

Answer (score 0):

Because Firejail increases attack surface in some respects, it is wise to limit FIrejail to be applicaiton specific on pre-configured SELinux distros. In the case of SELinux, you will want to find out first if your application is protected by SELinux, and if it is not, then it is wise to use firejail for that specific application instead.

List SELinux enforcements `semanage fcontext -l|grep appname`

Make sure Firejail has a profile you need or you build one first, check

`cd /etc/firejail`

`ls`

Before we create a symbolic link, we may wish to first find the file executable name, navigate to your program execution folder

for Ubuntu / Fedora / CentOS

`cd /usr/bin`

`ls`

Note the filename of the app you wish to sandbox. To create a symbolic link or symlink simply type:

`ln -s /usr/bin/firejail /usr/local/bin/program-name`

Thats it :)